# Can't get weather asynchronously using openweathermap API

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I'm trying to retrieve data using the openweathermap API.  I can get it to work, but I can't seem to do it asynchronously.  This causes the following error:

> Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**Form:**

```
  <label>Zipcode: </label>
  <form>
       <input type="text" id="locationField" name="locationField">
       <input type="submit" id="weatherSubmit" value="Get Weather">
  </form>
  <div>
      <br>
      <label>Location:</label>
      <div id="location"></div>
      <br>
      <label>Temperature:</label>
      <div id="temperature"></div>
      <br>
      <label>Humidity</label>
      <div id="humidity"></div>
  </div>
```

**Script:**

```
document.getElementById('weatherSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var zipcode = document.getElementById('locationField').value;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var payload = {location: null, temperature:null, humidity:null};
    req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + zipcode + ",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1", true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.addEventListener('load',function(){
      if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
          var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
          document.getElementById('location').textContent = response.name;
          document.getElementById('temperature').textContent = response.main.temp;
          document.getElementById('humidity').textContent = response.main.humidity;
      } else {
        console.log("Error in network request: " + request.statusText);
      }});
    req.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I can get this to work if I don't use AJAX, but that's not the way I want to do it.  The following code works if `foo()` is called onclick from the submit button and passes in the zip code value.

```
function foo(value) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + value + ",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1", false);
    req.send(null);
    var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    document.getElementById('location').textContent = response.name;
    var f = ((response.main.temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32;
    document.getElementById('temperature').textContent = f + "f";
    document.getElementById('humidity').textContent = response.main.humidity + "%";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first request be done via `POST` since you set a content type and send a request body?

Comment: It doesn't work whether it's `GET` or `POST`

Comment: You should probably remove your app id from your example code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `setRequestHeader`

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var payload = {location: null, temperature:null, humidity:null};
    req.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=02143,us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1", true);
    //req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.addEventListener('load',function(){
      if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
          var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
          console.log(response);
          //document.getElementById('location').textContent = response.name;
          //document.getElementById('temperature').textContent = response.main.temp;
          //document.getElementById('humidity').textContent = response.main.humidity;
      } else {
        console.log("Error in network request: " + request.statusText);
      }});
    req.send(null);
```

Works great!

BTW. Change your API key :(

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with CORS. The workaround is to use JSONP. It seems to be [supported](http://openweathermap.org/current#call) by OpenWeatherMap's API.

```
function foo(value) {
  window.weatherCallback = function(response) {
    document.getElementById('location').textContent = response.name;
    var f = ((response.main.temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32;
    document.getElementById('temperature').textContent = f + "f";
    document.getElementById('humidity').textContent = response.main.humidity
    delete window.weatherCallback; // delete the property
  };
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + value + ",us&appid=fa7d80c48643dfadde2cced1b1be6ca1&callback=weatherCallback';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Can't test it though, as I don't have the key for API.